# How do I update a password that's in a different format from the defined model? I'm getting DbEntityValidationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

**The Problem**

- I have a pre-defined `[StringLength()]` and `[RegularExpression()]` constraint on my Code-First Model.
- The `[StringLength()]` requirement is 8-16 characters
- The `[RegularExpression()]` constraint for the password is in a *different* format from the encrypted password.

  - The password is encrypted before being shoved into the database.
  - The encrypted password is 70 characters in length, which is higher than the 8-16 character limit defined in the Model.
- **I am required to use `e.Encrypt()`, meaning I cannot use the default ASP.NET hashing algorithm.**

I've searched high and low, but have yet to find the correct answer.

**My Code**

I have a function that allows a user to register an account. It looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register([Bind(Include="Username,Password,EmailAddress")] UserModel user)
{
    if (TryUpdateModel(user))
    {
        // Set password to a different format than Model's designated Regex
        user.Password = e.Encrypt(user.Password);

        context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Added;
        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }
    return View();
}
```

In my `UserModel.cs` file, I have the following constraints:

```
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(16, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 8 and 16 characters.")]
    [RegularExpression("^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]", ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage_PasswordRegex)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

Again, the hashed password is in a completely different format. Therefore, I cannot update it because it throws a `DbEntityValidationException`. This `[RegularExpression()]` is for the format of the user's password. I need to be able to bypass or suspend the password's Regex constraint.

**What I have done to remedy this**

I've removed the `[RegularExpression()]` requirements, and upped the `[StringLength()]` to 70, which is the length of my password hash.

However, I don't want to allow users to input 70 characters of text. This seems like a cheap hack, and I feel that there should be a better way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: may i ask, are you using the UserModel to bind? If so, may i sugest you have a view model for it? that way you can have the 70 character password on the model, but the required length on the view model for the controller

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by using the UserModel to bind? I apologize; I've only recently picked up MVC.

Comment: Don't apologize, it's ok. Please read this post, it explains quite well what i mean, and it will probably shine light in your path :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc

Comment: Use a different class to accept user input (the view model), then map those values to your `UserModel` in your controller. Put your input validation rules on your view model -- now you can have different validation rules for user input than what the database requires (because you have programmatically transformed those values).

Comment: Thank you. I've read that page, and am currently trying to fiddle with it, but the example provided is a little confusing to me. Is it possible to get a code sample of what you're talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example:

We've got different requirements for user input than what our database requires. We might need more user input which we will programmatically act upon.

The EF model

```
public class UserModel()
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(70)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Now here's the class we use to capture user input

```
public class UserViewModel()
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]", ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage_PasswordRegex)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Now we transform and map values.

The user won't know what to use for `Id` and the database doesn't have need for `ConfirmPassword`. We can also transform what the user originally entered as a password.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(UserViewModel model)
{
    if ((ModelState.IsValid) &&
        (model.Password == model.ConfirmPassword))
    {
        // map to EF model
        var user = new UserModel
        {
            Name = model.Name,
            Password = e.encrypt(model.Password)  // transform, encrypt, whatever
        };

        db.Users.Add(user);  // use EF model to persist
        ...

        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }
    return(model);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! It seems that I was close. The only problem was I inverted the `[RegularExpression()]` order. I had the `UsersModel` class trying to validate using the aforementioned pattern, whereas the `UsersViewModel` class was trying to accept a string length of `70`. I've accepted your answer. If you found my question informative and fitting for this website, please throw me an upvote so I can begin upvoting helpful comments and answers. Thank you.